# Kubernetes client delete returns true, if delete fails

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, fabric8

We are testing our code using the kubernetes client.

We experienced some interesting behaviour, in case of deletion e.g. a config map:

- `GET` return `200`, `DELETE` returns `200`: `delete()` returns `true`
- `GET` return `200`, `DELETE` returns `404`: `delete()` returns `true`
- `GET` return `404`, `DELETE` is not called at all: `delete()` returns `false`
- `GET` return `200`, `DELETE` returns `400`: `delete()` throws `KubernetesClientException`
- `GET` return `400`: `delete()` throws `KubernetesClientException`

So we wonder, if it is really consistent, that `200/404` returns `true` and `404/nc` returns `false`. Both should return `true` or both should return `false`.

So we wonder, is it perhaps a bug?

According `io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.delete()` it is meant to return `false` in case of `404`

```
  try {
    deleteList();
    return true;
  } catch (KubernetesClientException e) {
    if (e.getCode() != 404) {
      throw e;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Here is the test example:

```
// GET return 200
// DELETE return 200
// kubernetesClient.delete() return TRUE
server.expect().get().withPath(format("/api/v1/namespaces/{}/configmaps?labelSelector={}%3D{}", namespace, name, value)).andReturn(200, configMapList).once();
server.expect().delete().withPath(format("/api/v1/namespaces/{}/configmaps/{}", namespace, configMapName)).andReturn(200, StringUtils.EMPTY).once();
actual = kubernetesClient.configMaps().inNamespace(namespace).withLabelSelector(labelSelector).delete();
assertTrue(actual)

// GET return 200
// DELETE return 404
// kubernetesClient.delete() return TRUE
server.expect().get().withPath(format("/api/v1/namespaces/{}/configmaps?labelSelector={}%3D{}", namespace, name, value)).andReturn(200, configMapList).once();
server.expect().delete().withPath(format("/api/v1/namespaces/{}/configmaps/{}", namespace, configMapName)).andReturn(404, StringUtils.EMPTY).once();
actual = kubernetesClient.configMaps().inNamespace(namespace).withLabelSelector(labelSelector).delete();
assertTrue(actual)

// GET return 404
// kubernetesClient.delete() return FALSE
server.expect().get().withPath(format("/api/v1/namespaces/{}/configmaps?labelSelector={}%3D{}", namespace, name, value)).andReturn(404, StringUtils.EMPTY).once();
actual = kubernetesClient.configMaps().inNamespace(namespace).withLabelSelector(labelSelector).delete();
assertFalse(actual)

// GET return 200
// DELETE return 400
// kubernetesClient.delete() throws KubernetesClientException
server.expect().get().withPath(format("/api/v1/namespaces/{}/configmaps?labelSelector={}%3D{}", namespace, name, value)).andReturn(200, configMapList).once();
server.expect().delete().withPath(format("/api/v1/namespaces/{}/configmaps/{}", namespace, configMapName)).andReturn(400, StringUtils.EMPTY).once();
try {
    kubernetesClient.configMaps().inNamespace(namespace).withLabelSelector(labelSelector).delete();
    fail();
} catch (io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException e) {
    assertTrue(true);
}

// GET return 400
// kubernetesClient.delete() throws KubernetesClientException
server.expect().get().withPath(format("/api/v1/namespaces/{}/configmaps?labelSelector={}%3D{}", namespace, name, value)).andReturn(400, StringUtils.EMPTY).once();
try {
    kubernetesClient.configMaps().inNamespace(namespace).withLabelSelector(labelSelector).delete();
    fail();
} catch (io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException e) {
    assertTrue(true);
}
```